# Using hive to solve my task

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hiveql

So i have a task where insert a new record in a table .

i then query the same table for all historical records.

And compare all these historical records with the new record and store the matches in a different table.
now there is a problem that it blows out of proportion when theres huge amount of data.
and each new computation takes greater amount of time.

i can't cache the historical records as they may expire after a time frame and becomes obsolete.

The comparing task is fairly complex , so hence its in a java code.
I dont want to write a map reduce job to do this.

Is there a way i can use hive to do my task

Comment: i current have a multi threaded java application that does all of this. but its taking a performance hit. so i was thinking of splitting this comparision logic out of my java code and write a mapreduce program to process it. i wanted to check if i can use only hive for mapreduce part of my code?

Comment: i feel you can use Hive,for better answer, elaborate your question.

Comment: If you can express your comparison criteria in SQL, you would definitely benefit from Hive. Otherwise, Hive interface would not give you any advantages over a regular Map/Reduce job.